# Flat/Smooth Solutions To An Underdetermined Complex Linear System

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, complex-numbers

Is there a way to get flat/smooth solutions (in terms of magnitude) to an underdetermined complex system like there is for real systems? Specifically, for $b\in\mathbb{R}^M$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$, one can use regularization with the first/second derivatives to get a flatter/smoother solution:

$$
\min_x{ \Vert Ax-b \Vert + \lambda \Vert D_{\{1,2\}} x \Vert },
$$

where $\lambda \geq 0$, and $D_1$ and $D_2$ would be the first and second derivative operators, respectively.

For $b\in\mathbb{C}^M$ and $A\in\mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$, however, is there anything one can do?